# How To Pass A Method Reference With Parameter In Java?

Tags: java, lambda, method-reference

I don't know the exact name for it (I'm guessing method-reference) but here is what I'm talking about. Let's say I want to take the square root of all doubles in a double array. Then, if the array is called `arr`, I can do this:

```
Arrays.stream(arr).map(Math::sqrt). // ... box it and stuff
```

However, if I want to square each number in an int array, I'm thinking of using `Math.pow(num, 2)` as the method. However, `Math.pow` has a second parameter, but I know it will always be 2. So I'm thinking I can do something like this:

```
Arrays.stream(arr).map(Math::pow(2)). // ... box it and stuff
```

But this results in an error. What can I do?

Comment: I think you have two ways:
- Write a fun with 1 param (num), then return Math.pow(num, 2), use that fun for method reference.
- just use **it*it** for the square on map function without method reference.

Comment: You can't use a method reference here, just use a lambda instead. `.mapToDouble(n -> Math.pow(n, 2))`

Comment: Method reference only work if the method has the same input param + return type with the main method of target functional interface (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/functional-interfaces-java/)

Comment: I mean, if you use Math.pow(num, 2) directly it can't be referenced, if you write another method that have 1 param and return a double, that method can be referenced in this case, I'll show you the code if needed.

Comment: Or are you talking about [partial application](https://www.pgrs.net/2015/04/23/partial-function-application-in-java-8/)? (which, in this instance, would be overkill)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca no, I just want to explain how the method reference work to the asker.

Comment: @ThinkTwiceCodeOnce sorry for the confusion, that comment was meant for OP.

Answer (score 3):

you may use lambda and send Math.pow(n,2)

like this:

```
Stream.of(1.1,1.2,1.3).map(n -> Math.pow(n,2))
```

Comment: Do you know how to pass in a method reference instead of using a lambda? I'm just wondering if it's possible, because I think it makes it look cleaner.

Comment: @Higigig no, it would not make the code cleaner. It would make it look different, that’s all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple lambda expression.

```
Arrays.stream(arr).map(d -> Math.pow(d, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to implement this:

- First, use lambda expression:

  ```
  Arrays.stream(arr).map(num -> Math.pow(num, 2));
  ```
- Second, (if you still want to invoke a method reference here, and to understand correctly how method reference works): write another method that call Math.pow():

  ```
  Arrays.stream(arr).map(this::square);


  private double square(double num) {
      return Math.pow(num, 2);
  }
  ```